# Django Rest Framework and AWS Cognito

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, amazon-cognito

Currently, I am using django-warrant to utilize cognito (JWT) based authentication to access APIs. After creating pool and app,  I have set up following in my settings file:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
'django_warrant.backend.CognitoBackend',
]

COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID = 'poolid'
COGNITO_APP_ID = 'app id'
COGNITO_ATTR_MAPPING = {
   'email': 'email',
   'given_name': 'name',
   'family_name': 'last name',
}

COGNITO_CREATE_UNKNOWN_USERS = False

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'access_key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'access_key_secret'
```

In Midddleware, I have added:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    .............,
    'warrant.django.middleware.APIKeyMiddleware',
    ..............,
]
```

In Installed apps, I have added,

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ............,
    'django_warrant',
    ............,
 ]
```

In urls.py,  I have added:

```
path('accounts/', include('django_warrant.urls'))
```

When I try to hit accounts/login url, it is throwing the error of missing templates.

As I am using it for the first time, I am clueless how to proceed further with it to map django users with cognito users. I have searched tutorials related to this but found None. Please provide me guidance so that I can manage to proceed further.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @py_dude 
    TypeError at /accounts/login/
     login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'

Comment: can't you just post the whole traceback?

Comment: the error caused by passing wrong argument to a function not because the template is missing though

Comment: @py_dude But question is that I want to implement it on rest APIs, But I am unable to move ahead.